# Onclick event not selecting the correct switch option

Tags: javascript, onclick, switch-statement

My onclick event is not finding a switch option. I'm sure I have the wrong elements but cannot figure out where.  Any help would be wonderful!  I only did the first few to verify it was working before continuing with the remaining input values.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Operators</title>
  <script>

      function calcValue(elem) {
        var firstNumber = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
        var secondNumber = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
        var operator = document.getElementById("operator").value;
        operator = elem.value;
        switch (operator) {
          case "add":
            alert(firstNumber + " + " + secondNumber + " = " + (firstNumber +  secondNumber));
            break;
          case "div":
            alert(firstNumber + " / " + secondNumber + " = " + (firstNumber / secondNumber));
            break;
          case "mod":
            alert(firstNumber + " % " + secondNumber + " = " + (firstNumber % secondNumber));
            break;
          case "multiply":
            alert(firstNumber + " * " + secondNumber + " = " + (firstNumber * secondNumber));
            break;
          case "subtract":
            alert(firstNumber + " - " + secondNumber + " = " + (firstNumber - secondNumber));
            break;
        }
      }

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>firstNumber is 5</p>
  <p>secondNumber is 12</p>
    <p id="operator"></p>
    <input type="button" value="Addition" onclick="calcValue('add'.this);">
    <input type="button" value="Division" onclick="calcValue('div'.this);">
    <input type="button" value="Modulus" onclick="calcValue('mod');">
    <input type="button" value="Multiplication" onclick="calcValue('multiply');">
    <input type="button" value="Subtraction" onclick="calcValue('subtract');">
    <input type="button" value="Negation" onclick="calcValue('neg');">
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Equals ==" onclick="calcValue('equalto');">
    <input type="button" value="Not Equals !=" onclick="calcValue('notequalto');">
    <input type="button" value="Greater Than >" onclick="calcValue('greater');">
    <input type="button" value="Less Than <" onclick="calcValue('less');">
    <input type="button" value="Greater Than or Equal >=" onclick="calcValue('greaterequals');">
    <input type="button" value="Less Than or Equal <=" onclick="calcValue('lessequals');">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing. I can see that page but when I click on the buttons, nothing happens.

Comment: Can you make it into a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

### Check out the [Demo](http://jsexample.com/#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)

```html
<body>
  <p id="firstNum">firstNumber is 5</p>
  <p id="secondNum">secondNumber is 12</p>
  <input type="button" value="Addition" onclick="calcValue('add');">
  <input type="button" value="Division" onclick="calcValue('div');">
  <input type="button" value="Modulus" onclick="calcValue('mod');">
  <input type="button" value="Multiplication" onclick="calcValue('multiply');">
  <input type="button" value="Subtraction" onclick="calcValue('subtract');">
  <input type="button" value="Negation" onclick="calcValue('neg');">
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="Equals ==" onclick="calcValue('equalto');">
  <input type="button" value="Not Equals !=" onclick="calcValue('notequalto');">
  <input type="button" value="Greater Than >" onclick="calcValue('greater');">
  <input type="button" value="Less Than <" onclick="calcValue('less');">
  <input type="button" value="Greater Than or Equal >=" onclick="calcValue('greaterequals');">
  <input type="button" value="Less Than or Equal <=" onclick="calcValue('lessequals');">

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function calcValue(elem) {
      var firstNumber = document.getElementById("firstNum").textContent;
      firstNumber = firstNumber.match(/\d+/);
      var secondNumber = document.getElementById("secondNum").textContent;
      secondNumber = secondNumber.match(/\d+/);
      switch (elem) {
        case "add":
            alert(firstNumber + " + " + secondNumber + " = " + (parseInt(firstNumber) + parseInt(secondNumber)));
            break;
        case "div":
            alert(firstNumber + " / " + secondNumber + " = " + (parseInt(firstNumber) / parseInt(secondNumber)));
            break;
        case "mod":
            alert(firstNumber + " % " + secondNumber + " = " + (parseInt(firstNumber) % parseInt(secondNumber)));
            break;
        case "multiply":
            alert(firstNumber + " * " + secondNumber + " = " + (parseInt(firstNumber) * parseInt(secondNumber)));
            break;
        case "subtract":
            alert(firstNumber + " - " + secondNumber + " = " + (parseInt(firstNumber) - parseInt(secondNumber)));
            break;
      }
    }

  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

At glance I see a couple or three issues, but the most relevant is that I cannot find any element in your HTML code with id *firstNumber* and *secondNumber*. See NOTEs:

```
  function calcValue(elem) {
    // NOTE: Your are trying to get an element by an id that does not exist.
    var firstNumber = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
    // NOTE: Again, your are trying to get an element by an id that does not exist.
    var secondNumber = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
    var operator = document.getElementById("operator").value;
    // NOTE: Are you sure you are calling calcValue with an HTMLElement?
    operator = elem.value;
    switch (operator) {
      case "add":
        alert(firstNumber + " + " + secondNumber + " = " + (firstNumber +  secondNumber));
        break;
      case "div":
        alert(firstNumber + " / " + secondNumber + " = " + (firstNumber / secondNumber));
        break;
      case "mod":
        alert(firstNumber + " % " + secondNumber + " = " + (firstNumber % secondNumber));
        break;
      case "multiply":
        alert(firstNumber + " * " + secondNumber + " = " + (firstNumber * secondNumber));
        break;
      case "subtract":
        alert(firstNumber + " - " + secondNumber + " = " + (firstNumber - secondNumber));
        break;
    }
  }
```

Also, be careful what you are passing to calcValue in the *onclick* property. Javascript will fail "silently" and it will give you the impression that nothing happens.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py "Give a man a fish, he eats for a day; teach a man to fish, he eats for a lifetime". It's clear that Heather is learning so I think we are doing a disservice to Heather or Heather's like people if we just write the code for themselves. Sorry I had not enough reputation points to make this comment in another place :).